# How can I make the camera follow a path later on during the animation?

Tags: camera

I've been working on a building animation where the camera is showcasing different steps of building a house. I want to make the camera zoom out and rotate around the house as the final part, but when I add a follow path constraint, the camera just flies far away from the path. I watched couple of tutorials and all of them relocated the camera to 0, 0, 0 and it was **at the beginning** of the animation. I didn't use any other path up until this point, only animated the cameras location. I also tried the *influence* property and faced the same flying away issue.

What am I suppose to do? Am I using the influence property correctly? Is there another way to do this? TIA.

Comment: Don't click on the Animate Path button of the Follow Path constraint, instead create some keyframes on the Offset value for example, haveyou tried and if so, what problem have you met with this method?

Comment: @moonboots the thing is, as soon as I add the follow path constraint to the camera, it just flies away. I tried to set the location of camera to origin, then added the constraint but it didn't work. I tried to animate offset, it didn't work. Thanks for responding

Comment: you need to press Alt G to bring back the camera to the beginning of the curve, but you may have already created location keyframe for the camera, which will make it fly away, so open the timeline and check if you don't need to remove these keyframes. You could also share your file (keep only the useful elements like camera and curve): https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: @moonboots I did create location keyframes, so yeah that's probably why it keeps flying away. I think since the camera is already away from the origin point, even though I use Alt G to bring the camera to the curve, it's still far away: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=d6XedSSB" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/d6XedSSB/)

Comment: Yes you have plenty of location keyframes for the camera, if you want to keep them aside for some reason, open the Dope Sheet, switch it to Action Editor, click on the X button to close the action. Now when you'll press Alt G the camera will stick to the curve, use the Offset value to animate

Comment: @moonboots That just deletes all the previous keyframes of the camera, no? I need those keyframes. Excuse my dumb questions, I am a blender noob if it wasn't obvious earlier

Comment: If you do what I say (close the action, not delete the keyframes) it won't delete the keyframes, it will keep them apart, you just need to scrool through the action dropdown menu of the Dope Sheet (in Action mode). If you need the already existing keyframes for the current action (camera spinning around) then parent the camera to an empty and give the Follow Path to the empty instead?

Comment: When you say that you need these keyframes, do you mean that you want to add the current animations of the camera to the camera rotating around the curve?

Comment: @moonboots What I mean is that the camera will be animated like normally (rotation, zoom in/out etc.) until, for example, the 1500th keyframe. Then, it will go to the beginning of the path and be animated along that path. I just want the camera to not be influenced by the path until a certain point

Comment: You could do it with the Influence, but if you simply want your camera to rotate around, you could simply parent it to an empty, and rotate the empty whenever you want

Comment: If you still want to use the Follow Path, the frame before when it is supposed to begin keyframe the Influence at 0, also put the 3D cursor at the camera location and keyframe the camera location, the frame when it is supposed to begin keyframe the Influence at 1, bring back manually the camera to the 3D cursor location and keyframe the camera location. There must be a more elegant way but this works

Comment: Hi, there.. it's a real shame you can't be at the same desk.. commentary is a far from ideal channel to exchange all the info. you need to, here... I'll move this to chat so you can continue, but if there's still no fix, maybe it would be a good idea to share a stripped-down version of the problem on https://blend-exchange.com/ , after finding a way to describe or illustrate the end-effect that you want, and are not getting.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151362/discussion-on-question-by-prims3s-how-can-i-make-the-camera-follow-a-path-later); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 0):

You could keyframe the *Influence* of the *Follow Path* constraint but for someting as simple as the camera rotating along a circle, the simplest solution is to parent your camera to an empty, and begin to rotate the empty when the camera is supposed to rotate.